# Unable to access error login form codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am creating a login form, I wrote everything from documentation and from other resources. When I try to login I am getting an error of `Unable to access an error message corresponding to your field name Username.(xss_clean)` and `Unable to access an error message corresponding to your field name Password.(xss_clean)`

I checked my database from phpMyAdmin, database is already there. I checked my connection of databse, it's also connected. I checked then table admin it's also there and coded in model.

Can you guys help me, what is wrong I did here?

Controller

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class LoginCheck extends CI_Controller {

    public function __construct(){
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->library('form_validation');
        $this->load->database();
        $this->load->helper('form');
        $this->load->helper('url');
        $this->load->model('admin');
    }

    function index() {
        //This method will have the credentials validation
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('username', 'Username', 'trim|required|xss_clean');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('password', 'Password', 'trim|required|xss_clean|callback_check_database');

        $this->form_validation->set_error_delimiters('<br /><div class="form-error">', '</span>');

    if($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE) {
        //Field validation failed.  User redirected to login page
        $this->load->view('index');
    }

    else {
        //Go to private area
        echo "Private area";
        //redirect('listing', 'refresh');
    }
}

    function check_database($password) {
        //Field validation succeeded.  Validate against database
        $username = $this->input->post('username');
        //query the database
        $result = $this->admin->login($username, $password);
        //print_r($result);

    if($result) {
        $sess_array = array();
        foreach($result as $row) {
            $sess_array = array(
            'id' => $row->id,
            'username' => $row->username
            );
            $this->session->set_userdata('logged_in', $sess_array);
        }
        return TRUE;
    }
        else {
            $this->form_validation->set_message('check_database', 'Invalid username or password');
            return false;
        }
    }
}

?>
```

View

```
<?php
$attributes = array('class' => 'login100-form validate-form flex-sb flex-w');
echo form_open('index.php/logincheck', $attributes);
?>
<span class="login100-form-title p-b-51">
<img src="<?php echo site_url('login_assets/img/logo.png')?>">
</span>
<div class="wrap-input100 validate-input m-b-16" data-validate = "Username is required">
<?php echo form_error('username'); ?>
<input class="input100" type="text" name="username" value="<?php echo set_value('username'); ?>" placeholder="Username">
<span class="focus-input100"></span>
</div>
<div class="wrap-input100 validate-input m-b-16" data-validate = "Password is required">
<?php echo form_error('password'); ?>
<input class="input100" type="password" name="password" value="<?php echo set_value('password'); ?>" placeholder="Password">
<span class="focus-input100"></span>
</div>
<div class="container-login100-form-btn m-t-17">
<?php 
$attributes = array('class' => 'login100-form-btn');
echo form_submit('submit', 'Login', $attributes);
?>
</div>
<?php echo form_close(); ?>
```

Comment: The model is unnecesary here, so if you need to keep it private, you may edit it out... the error is coming from form_validation. It's worth noting that the last validation rule shouldn't be followed by a pipe. Try using `trim|required` on both set_rules statements

Comment: I updated my `set_rules`, I mistakenly posted wrong `set_rules`

Comment: and the error persists?

Comment: Yes error `Unable to access an error message corresponding to your field name Username.(xss_clean)` and `Unable to access an error message corresponding to your field name Password.(xss_clean)`

Comment: Oh, didn't see you were now using xss_clean. Keep in mind that xss_clean was deprecated from the main form_validation rules. Now it's only available through the security helper which you are not loading. That said, the previous error went away with the removal of the trailing pipe and now the error comes from xss_clean... you should either load the security helper or not use xss_clean altogether to validate input, as xss filtering should be done on output, not input

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that your original validation rules had a tiny mistake. In CI, the final validation rule shouldn't be followed by a pipe `|`. The pipe should only be used as a delimiter in this case.

Try changing your validation rules to remove the trailing pipe:

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('username', 'Username', 'rule1|rule2|rule3');
$this->form_validation->set_rules('password', 'Password', 'rule1|rule2');
```

Also, note that your form is pointed to the `LoginCheck` class, but it's not pointed to any specific function/method. Even though it may default to `index()` the form should point to the specific class/method so you should use

`echo form_open('index.php/logincheck/index', $attributes);`

Finally, your updated rules include `xss_clean`, which was removed from CI's form validation library and required the security helper to be loaded. You may get around the error by loading the security helper in the construct, but don't forget that XSS filtering is supposed to be done on output, not input (which is why it was removed from the form validation lib)

You may read a bit about this last part [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45253878/how-to-overcome-xss-clean-error-in-codeigniter)